# What output of the both program is different?

Tags: java, c++

There are two program have same logic, one is in C++ and second is in JAVA. why output of the both program is not same ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    printf("He");
    do
    {
        while(i<5)
        {
            cout<<"Hello";
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(1);
}
```

What will be output of the program and why ??

Now same logic in JAVA

```
class Demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i=1;
        do
        {
            while(i<5)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                i++;
            }
        }
        while(true);
    }
}
```

what will be output of java program ?? 
how it different ??

Comment: Why not try it out both?

Comment: Programs don't have the same logic, your C++ program is first calling a `printf()` , than calling `cout` without `endl`, while your java program just calls a `System.out.println()` which flushes the stream.

Comment: `what will be output of java program ??` We are not a Java compiler / virtual machine. Please ask that question from one that is. `What will be output of the program ` We are not a c++ compiler either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one won't have any output since the stdout stream wasn't flushed by a newline (or a manual call).

In Java, the method called is println, so it's adding a newline at the end of the string, causing the stream to flush.